# Hibernate validator for smallrye/quarkus @ConfigMapping throwing exception and not printing message

Tags: java, quarkus, hibernate-validator, smallrye

I created the following interface in Quarkus to validate the values in the properties in my application.properties. I added hibernate-validator and created a custom validator to validate a certain field.  If I use the correct value the application loads normally, but if I use an invalid value I get a cryptic stack trace. I want to print the messages I wrote in the validation annotation.

```
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "market-data", namingStrategy = ConfigMapping.NamingStrategy.KEBAB_CASE)
public interface MarketDataProperties {

    @NotNull(message = "type cannot be null.")
    @StringEnumeration(enumClass = MarketDataType.class, message = "valid values can be either BID or OFFER")
    String type();

    @NotNull(message = "market-id cannot be null")
    String marketID();

    @Min(value = 1, message = "top-of-book-limit has to be a min of 1")
    int topOfBookLimit();

    @NotNull(message = "store-name cannot be null")
    String storeName();

    default String aggregateStoreName() {
        return String.format("%s_AGG", this.storeName());
    }

    enum MarketDataType {
        BID("0"), OFFER("1");

        private String value;

        private MarketDataType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.value;
        }

    }
}
```

@StringEnumaration is a custom validator for the enum.

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = StringEnumerationValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER,
        ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface StringEnumeration {

    String message() default "{com.xxx.bean.validation.constraints.StringEnumeration.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();

}
```

```
public class StringEnumerationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<StringEnumeration, String> {

    private Set<String> AVAILABLE_ENUM_NAMES;

    public static Set<String> getNamesSet(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) {
        Enum<?>[] enums = e.getEnumConstants();
        String[] names = new String[enums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < enums.length; i++) {
            names[i] = enums[i].name();
        }
        Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
        return mySet;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(StringEnumeration stringEnumeration) {
        Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumSelected = stringEnumeration.enumClass();
        AVAILABLE_ENUM_NAMES = getNamesSet(enumSelected);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return AVAILABLE_ENUM_NAMES.contains(value);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the cryptic exception I get:

```
ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile [dev]): javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: RequestScoped context was not active when trying to obtain a bean instance for a client proxy of CLASS bean [class=io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.CurrentVertxRequest, id=9260aa608251c44230eeb9b234f605844a7622bf]
        - you can activate the request context for a specific method using the @ActivateRequestContext interceptor binding
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getDelegate(ClientProxies.java:55)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.CurrentVertxRequest_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.CurrentVertxRequest_ClientProxy.getCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.locale.ResteasyReactiveLocaleResolver.getHeaders(ResteasyReactiveLocaleResolver.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.locale.AbstractLocaleResolver.getAcceptableLanguages(AbstractLocaleResolver.java:31)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.locale.AbstractLocaleResolver.resolve(AbstractLocaleResolver.java:17)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.locale.ResteasyReactiveLocaleResolver.resolve(ResteasyReactiveLocaleResolver.java:18)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.locale.LocaleResolversWrapper.resolve(LocaleResolversWrapper.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.AbstractMessageInterpolator.interpolate(AbstractMessageInterpolator.java:343)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.validationcontext.AbstractValidationContext.interpolate(AbstractValidationContext.java:322)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.validationcontext.AbstractValidationContext.addConstraintFailure(AbstractValidationContext.java:231)
```

How do I get it to print the validation message instead of this stacktrace?

Comment: I faced the same problem yesterday; the problem is in io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.locale.ResteasyReactiveLocaleResolver.resolve(line 18) because a @requestcontext object is requested and request scope is not active. Open a ticket in quarkus with a reproduce attached

Comment: Which version of Quarkus are you using? Using older/ newer version fix the error?

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/31434